# Porting a Groovy DSL to Clojure

Tags: javascript, groovy, clojure, dsl, nashorn

I have several "builder" Groovy DSL made with FactoryBuilderSupport ([SwingBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Swing+Builder) being the canonical example) and mainly because of performance issues (and also because I'm worried about Groovy's future, e.g. will Groovy 3 include a new MOP?), I'm looking at alternative frameworks for a JVM-based internal DSL.

As Clojure has both closures and macros, it is a worthy candidate, but I don't know how easy it is with Clojure to manipulate dynamicaly bound Java objects like in Groovy scripts (btw I'm familiar with LISP language familiy but not with Clojure's specific features).

Also, I guess that if I wait long enough, Java 8's Nashorn would add Javascript as another possible candidate.

So, how good would Clojure (or maybe even JavaScript) be at supporting that kind of DSL compared to Groovy ?

Comment: Why the new MOP worries you?

Comment: I'm worried that it won't make the cut in Groovy 3. And the current one has some nasty issues.

Comment: Bring your ideas and worries: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/GEP+11+-+Groovy+3+semantics+and+new+MOP

Comment: Could you include an example of a dynamicaly bound Java object in Groovy to provide some context for answering this question? It's not clear (to me) what an answer would look like for this question

Comment: @Arthur, are you familiar with the fact that Groovy "closures" are not really "closures" because of how they (dynamically) resolve free identifiers ?

Comment: Since you mention SwingBuilder, you may be interested in https://github.com/daveray/seesaw

Comment: @Arthur, to make things more clear : I think that if I wanted to replicate the behavior of Groovy "closures" in Scheme, I would give a try with non-hygienic macros. As I'm not that familiar with Lisp (and Clojure) MOP, I don't know well it could do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure is probably the best JVM language to creates DSLs with because it has macros.
Some examples that may inspire you (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968289/476116):

- [Enlive](http://github.com/cgrand/enlive/) (HTML templating)
- [LazyTest](http://github.com/stuartsierra/lazytest) (Unit testing)
- [fnparse](http://github.com/joshua-choi/fnparse) (parser generator)
- [Midje](http://github.com/marick/Midje) (testing & mocking)
- [byte-spec](http://github.com/rosejn/byte-spec) (binary-formats)
- [Vijual](http://github.com/drcode/vijual) (graph layout)
- [Trammel](http://github.com/fogus/trammel) (constraint programming)
- [Cascalog](http://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog) (Hadoop w/ datalog syntax)
- [Incanter](http://github.com/liebke/incanter) (R-like environment)
- [Sandbar](http://github.com/brentonashworth/sandbar) (HTML sessions, forms, auth)
- [ClojureQL](https://github.com/LauJensen/clojureql) (SQL)
- [mini-kanren](http://github.com/jduey/mini-kanren) (embedded logic programming)
- [Leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) (build tool)
- [sexpbot](http://github.com/Raynes/sexpbot) (IRC bot with plugin arch)

And of course [seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw) as an example of a swing DSL.